# SimpleDateFormat (Unparseable Exception)

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to convert a string (from database) to date. But I get Unparseable Exception. DateFrom and DateTo columns are VarChar data types.

Here's the Code:

```
DateFormat DateF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);

HashMap<Date, Date> checkBothDate = new HashMap<Date, Date>();

rss = sta.executeQuery("select DateFrom, DateTo from table where EmpID = '" + session.getAttribute("EmpID") + "' ");
while (rss.next()) {
   String addDate1 = "";
   String addDate2 = "";

   addDate1 = rss.getString("DateFrom");
   addDate2 = rss.getString("DateTo");

   Date checkFromDate = DateF.parse(addDate1); 
   Date checkToDate = DateF.parse(addDate2);

   checkBothDate.put(checkFromDate, checkToDate);
}

boolean isInBetweenDate = false;

Set set = checkBothDate.entrySet();
Iterator itr = set.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {

  Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) itr.next();

  date1Check = (Date)mapEntry.getKey();
  date2Check = (Date)mapEntry.getValue();

}

if (d1.after(date1Check) || d1.before(date2Check) || d2.after(date1Check) || d2.before(date2Check)) {
                isInBetweenDate = true;
}

if (isInBetweenDate == true) {
                session.setAttribute("Error", "The date overlaps.");
} else {
   //something add in the database
}
```

The sample output is:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-01-05"
```

The example output is from DateFrom column.

Comment: Have you considered `rss.getDate("DateFrom")` and `rss.getDate("DateTo")`?

Comment: [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: What data types do `DateFrom` and `DateTo` have in the DB -- `VARCHAR` or `DATE`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer no, because the datatype of DateFrom and DateTo is Varchar.

Comment: @C.Muchanx Which is a bad idea, but is not an excuse not to use `PreparedStatements`

Comment: @MickMnemonic VarChar.

Comment: Are you sure that the data in the DB matches the `yyyy-MM-dd` format _exactly_, i.e. that there is no extra whitespace etc.

Comment: What your current Culture ?

Comment: Your posted code works for me with your provided input, please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes, I'm sure that it matches exactly.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I updated the post.

Comment: You can try printing the `addDate1` and `addDate2` before parsing to confirm the dates are correct.

Comment: `//I think the exception starts here.` See all those “at” lines underneath the `java.text.ParseException` output?  That is called a stack trace.  It tells you *exactly* where the exception has occurred.  Read it and use it to determine precisely which line of your code is causing exception;  do not guess.  I think you'll find that it's occurring in your second `while` loop, since there is no chance your DateFormat can correctly parse the output of a Date's toString method.

Comment: @VGR I'm using jsp, and I run it straight to the browser.

Comment: How do you know about the exception at all?

Comment: @VGR a popup message shows: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-01-05"

Comment: If possible, run your application in a debugger.  Alternatively, you can (as a temporary measure) wrap your code in a try/catch block and use the caught exception's printStackTrace method to see where your problem is.  You will find this much more productive than guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are converting Date object to string and parsing using format "yyyy-MM-dd" which is not possible.

**Added Date object to map**

```
  Date checkFromDate = DateF.parse(addDate1); 
  Date checkToDate = DateF.parse(addDate2);
  checkBothDate.put(checkFromDate, checkToDate);
```

**And then parsing the toString of the date which will be somthing like "Wed Jan 13 10:37:21 IST 2016"** and resulting parsing exception

```
date1 = mapEntry.getKey().toString();
date2 = mapEntry.getValue().toString();
date1Check = DateF.parse(date1);
date2Check = DateF.parse(date2);
```

**You have to avoid following statements of date parsing**

```
date1Check = DateF.parse(date1);
date2Check = DateF.parse(date2);
```

**instead of just get object from map and compare**

```
date1Check = mapEntry.getKey();
date2Check = mapEntry.getValue();
```

**And have to compare your date object like**

```
d1.after(date1Check)
```

Comment: @C.Muchanx, let me know what you find?

Comment: But it says that it is incompatible type.

Comment: is this for date1Check = mapEntry.getKey(); line?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: try to cast it date1Check = (Date)mapEntry.getKey();

Comment: It still has the parsing exception.

Comment: no, can you please edit your question with what you tried with my answer?

Comment: scratching my head, try to print values of fromdate and todate. Also add Locale as new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);

Comment: still not working? have you printed the values of rss.getString("DateFrom"), but that values is already printed in exception, so that is not issue.

Comment: can you add complete stack tress of exception? it will give more details about exception